# Limit resources to tenant in apache multi tenant configuration

Tags: php, apache, resources, limit

I'm going to deploy a multi tenant cloud service based on LAMP stack.
Each user has his own third domain .myservice.com, thus its own virtual host in Apache.

I'm wondering if it is possible and how I could limit resources any single virtual host can absorbe, so that even in case of high load from an user, it's not allowed to slow down too much the whole machine.

It's not really a multi tenant software at the moment, as each customer has a separate database and currentlu I use separate web folders containing the same project file.
This is not the best solution, but it's not the subject of this question and probably in the next future I'm going to use a single web folder for ann the users, with separate databases.

I'm using the standard apache-php configuration so that all is running under www-data user.

I'd really appreciate any kind of help.

Thank you,

Michele

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at techcello.com. They have built a SaaS framework in .NET covering all of your requirements from tenant on-boarding, subscription, billing, trial management, notifications, data backup and much more which can be used to kick-start any SaaS product.

As per you requirement you have complete control of your data since they just provide you the binaries and you need to host it yourself.